# Is there pervasive racial bias in United States policing?

Tags: united-states, police, racism

Twitter user Leonydus Johnson [posted](https://twitter.com/LeonydusJohnson/status/1267466345844740098) the following statistics acquired from the FBI UCR Program website and the Washington Post:

> For every 10,000 black people arrested for violent crime, 3 are killed
>
> For every 10,000 white people arrested for violent crime, 4 are killed"

He claims that they show that there is not pervasive racial bias in the way African-Americans are treated by the police in the United States. Are these statistics misleading or potentially inaccurate in any way?

Comment: Last I checked, around 50% of victims of unjustified police homicides were black, relative to 15 percent of the US population. And, depending on where these data are taken from, the percentage may in reality be larger (or even smaller), depending on how justification was determined.

Comment: This question seems like a better fit for [skeptics.se], since it's evaluating the truth of a published statement. I'd recommend migrating it

Comment: @Obie2.0 The posted rates for shootings are cherry-picked.  The [actual study that generated those numbers](https://www.nber.org/papers/w22399) shows no bias in officer shootings, true, but it finds pervasive bias at lower levels of force.

Comment: The author requested to migrate this question to Skeptics Stack Exchange. But unfortunately I can not do this because the question was posted too long ago.

Comment: Just so it's said, this is an excellent example of the abuse of statistics. Even if we grant that the statistics themselves are accurate (which is debatable) the population used is both skewed and improperly framed.  The population is 'people arrested for violent crimes': note how this (a) excludes people killed during minor crimes and traffic stops, and (b) fails to consider whether blacks are arrested for violent crimes (and thus killed) at far higher rates.

Comment: @TedWrigley If you look at https://ucr.fbi.gov/leoka/2019/topic-pages/tables/table-44.xls, you will see that the opposite is also true: police officers are more likely to be killed by blacks (40% are killed). This is consistent with homicides in general, with blacks accounting for 50% of homicides. It seems to me that police officers are simply more cautious around blacks and will more likely pull the trigger because it's statistically more likely the suspect will retaliate. This explanation is also consistent with the fact "other races" are less likely to get killed out of both white/blacks.

Comment: @Ray: That (even if true) doesn't make the statistical misuse any better, and would be perfectly consistent with the idea that police use racial biases against blacks: i.e., the number of police killed by offenders will be proportional to the number of confrontations police have with offenders, suggesting that police confront blacks at a far higher rate than they confront whites. This whole discussion is riddled with bad, misleading statistics.

Comment: @TedWrigley You are right, I agree they confront blacks at a far higher rate. I just think the reason police officers confront blacks at a higher rate is because on average, they commit more crime... ie it doesn't really have anything to do with police officers just confronting them to pester them and it could have easily been another race if they committed more crime (on average). I believe this is the case because if it were not, then I would expect the "other races" category to be higher than the white category in crime/arrests.

Comment: @Ray: Why would you suggest that blacks commit more crime on average than whites? Do you believe that blacks are inherently (racially or genetically) more inclined towards criminal behavior? Do you believe that society forces blacks into situations where criminal behavior is necessary for survival? Do you believe that blacks are surveilled more heavily than whites, and thus are caught in crimes at higher rates (even though they commit crimes at the same rates)? Or do you have some other explanation? You can't just drop a turd like that in the conversation without justifying it...

Comment: @Ray: Be aware: the first is a standard canard of racists and white supremacists, the second is a typical progressive sociological approach, the third is a fairly standard claim within the black activist community. I didn't just pull these theories out of thin air. You can choose whichever explanation you prefer, or something else entirely, but I won't allow you to shrug the statement off without explanation. Your answer will tell us what company you keep, which is something I think we are all interested in knowing.

Comment: @TedWrigley Why would you suggest that blacks commit more crime on average than whites? It's simple, I believe that 99% of police officers are not racists and couldn't care less about "catching more blacks than whites". Like in most industries, most people simply go do their jobs so they can return back to their families (ie they care more about family than their job): https://www.pewforum.org/2018/11/20/where-americans-find-meaning-in-life/. Which is why I'm more inclined to say that blacks commit more crimes than whites.

Comment: @Ray: I'm sorry, but that's nit an explanation. All you've said is "Few if any police are biased; arrests must therefore be fair; blacks must therefore commit more crimes". But I didn't ask you about the statistic; I asked you what factors made the statistic *true*. I mean, if you're going to stick with "The police are always good, just, and right" then you are echoing authoritarian nationalist worldviews (that's the kind of statement that would be put out by Orwell's "Ministry of Truth"). But still, it doesn't tell me why blacks *would be* more criminal than whites. People are people, no?

Comment: @TedWrigley However, I do not think blacks are more inherently inclined towards criminal behavior as far as genetics go. However, I do think culture plays a large part. For example, if you look at black immigrant vs U.S-born-blacks, you will see large differences: black immigrants are more likely to be married, more likely to have college education etc... https://www.pewresearch.org/social-trends/2015/04/09/chapter-1-statistical-portrait-of-the-u-s-black-immigrant-population/.

Comment: @Ray: I'm finding that last comment a bit unclear. is it suggesting that US blacks have a particular (and unfortunate) position within US culture that fosters broken homes and minimal opportunities? Or is it suggesting that US blacks have an idiosyncratic culture that have chosen for themselves, completely independent of and unrelated to broader US culture and history? Again, the first view is generally proposed by progressives, while the second is something of a mainstay in white nationalist circles.

Comment: @TedWrigley What I'm trying to say is I believe blacks commit more crimes because of their culture and not genetics. This culture predisposes them to failure in society. This statement is supported by the comparison between US-black vs black immigrants, asians (many were brought in for cheap labor/were POWs) vs US-black. Now I'm not saying racism has 0 effect as far as crime/arrests are concerned, I just think that racism cannot explain or even come close to explaining the large differences in crime/arrests statistics between blacks and whites.

Answer (score 17):

First, the claim is not exactly well defined. The FBI data gives arrest rates per arrest type, while the Washington Post gives deaths per population, so it's not clear if the numbers presented are meaningful or how the author arrived at that conclusion.  Additionally, it's unclear how to normalize events that can be repeated vs not; that is, a single person [can be arrested multiple times in a year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recidivism), while they can presumably only be killed once. And additionally, he didn't discuss the impact of race on the likeliness of being arrested in the first place (more on this below).

Second, the [lead of the Washington Post's "Fatal Force" project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wesley_Lowery) (source of the twitter data) responded to the post on twitter saying,

> Hey. You’re making this argument based on my data. Your conclusions are factually inaccurate

Now, for your question:

> These seem to indicate that there is not pervasive racial bias in the US police force. Are these statistics misleading or potentially inaccurate in any way?

While the twitter post linked to the 2018 dataset, the [current 2020 version](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/investigations/police-shootings-database/), has this summary at the end

> Although half of the people shot and killed by police are white, black Americans are shot at a disproportionate rate. They account for less than 13 percent of the U.S. population, but are killed by police at more than twice the rate of white Americans. Hispanic Americans are also killed by police at a disproportionate rate.

[image]

So, in absolute terms, there are more white people killed by police. This is perhaps not surprising since the dataset lists that population as almost four times larger than any other ethnicity. But as pointed out above, "The rate at which **black Americans are killed by police** is more than twice as high as **the rate for white Americans.** [em. original]"

For further reading, I would recommend [this Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/opinions/wp/2018/09/18/theres-overwhelming-evidence-that-the-criminal-justice-system-is-racist-heres-the-proof/) outlining a number of studies evaluating systemic racism related to the criminal justice system.

> Of particular concern to some on the right is the term “systemic racism,” often wrongly interpreted as an accusation that everyone in the system is racist. In fact, systemic racism means almost the opposite. It means that we have systems and institutions that produce racially disparate outcomes, regardless of the intentions of the people who work within them.

There are some dissenting studies listed above, but the majority of studies point out that non-whites are disproportionately represented at each step of the criminal justice system (being pulled over; arrest; jail; bond disparity; prison sentence harshness; probation being revoked; parole).

---

Are these statistics misleading? Statistics are notoriously difficult to get right, and easily manipulated (lies, damn lies, and statistics). The author's intent seemed to be to challenge whether police killings are racially biased. And there was a study on the list WaPo page that said class (income) was the most important factor when determining police engagement frequency. But with all the other data, and including comments from the original author lead, I'm skeptical that the post on twitter holds merit.

Comment: (+1) Regarding your last point, even for some data in this area that hasn't been contested in itself, there are some issue with drawing conclusions from it https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43730/are-white-and-non-white-police-officers-equally-likely-to-kill-black-suspects

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am working through that WaPo article right now, but it's long. I agree that the original author's comments are fairly convincing that Mr. Johnson has misrepresented something, although I'm still not sure precisely how. I was previously aware, as was Mr. Johnson, of the higher shooting rate of black Americans by police. The question remains of whether this can be explained by higher crime rates by blacks, or perhaps police mistreatment of the poor, etc, as opposed to racial bias in the police force. The rest of the justice system is beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: There's an incommensurability of benchmarks that no one addresses but needs to be addressed before we start talking about bias in police killings at least. Do we use population or some modified measure of interaction rates with (noting that there's racial bias when it comes to interaction rates but there's also higher crime rates in black communities)? I'd also note that the Wesley IIRC, the WaPo person you quoted, said he didn't like the conclusion drawn *because* it didn't use the population benchmark, therefore it amounts to begging the question. Not a fair outlook on the situation imo.

Comment: Yeah, if you go by percentage of *population*, Black people are over-represented among police shooting victims.  But if you go by percentage of *arrests*, then the proportion is about what's expected.

Comment: @jeremy909 If you want to substantially change your question (to be about something other than the twitter comment), you should open a new question on this site. If you are trying to decide if People of Color commit more crimes than Whites, go through the sources on the WaPo article. Here's a chart to get you started: https://www.hamiltonproject.org/charts/rates_of_drug_use_and_sales_by_race_rates_of_drug_related_criminal_justice

Comment: @BurnsBA Here's thought to follow if you can:  steroid abuse by police officers accused of use of unnecessary force. Police officers, especially those working in areas with high violent crime rates, have a high rate of steroid use/abuse, e.g. https://abcnews.go.com/US/story?id=3745740  Anyone who ever spent much time in a serious gym in the US could tell you that... But steroid abuse has a side effect - ['roid rage](https://www.drugabuse.gov/publications/research-reports/steroids-other-appearance-performance-enhancing-drugs-apeds/how-does-anabolic-steroid-misuse-affect-behavior)

Comment: @BurnsBA: To make a fair comparison, you would need to compare crime & arrest rates in communities with different racial/ethnic makeup but similar economic circumstances.  WRT the chart in your link, white Manhattanites who can afford good lawyers along with their cocaine habits are going to be treated much differently than poor white Appalachians using opiates to dull their back pain, just as drug using black media & sports personalities are going to be treated differently than poor black people from the inner cities.

Answer (score 1):

A question like this is actually better suited for the skeptics then politics, luckily skeptics have already covered the question here:  [Are African Americans victims of a disproportionate number of police killings?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34539/are-african-americans-victims-of-a-disproportionate-number-of-police-killings?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The short version is that it's complicated, there are definitely a higher proportion of police shootings of black then white individuals once one adjusts for population size, but some arguments can be made that other demographics (which I'd argue all trace back to socioeconomic differences caused by racism of past and present) may explain the differences in deaths; thus making it hard to say definitively that the differences are caused specifically by racism.

Put even simpler, probably, but it's pretty hard to definitively prove racism as a cause in such a large, and difficult to create controlled tests for, a population; so there will always be other possible explanations.